# javascript add variable to input field rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Javascript variable which gets the value of the select box. I would like to append input field with value = the value of select box. However, could not get this to work.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#extra_crew", function (e) {
        var extra_crew = $('#extra_crew').val();
        $('#extra_crew_area').append(
                ' <div class="col-sm-12 m-t-10 m-b-10 no-padding">'
                + '<%= text_field_tag :reservation_type, "", class: "form-control m-b-10", :value => "' 
                + extra_crew 
                + '" %>'
                + '</div>');
        console.log(extra_crew);
    });
});
```

It works just fine but extra_crew seems a string in the input field could not concatenate.

Then it shows like this.

[image]

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `+extra_crew+`

Comment: @Anand did not work, still string as +extra_crew+

Comment: extra_crew_area is a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to call `html_safe` on the string `"'+extra_crew+'"` to tell rails to render it without escaping the quotes to html entities:

```
+'<%= text_field_tag :reservation_type, "", class: "form-control m-b-10", :value => "'+extra_crew+'".html_safe %>'
```

However, I'm not sure this will work - a more conventional approach would be to create the div and then and text field entirely in javascript instead of trying to use Rails to create the input tag - something like this:

```
var newDiv = $("<div>", {id: "foo", class: "col-sm-12 m-t-10 m-b-10 no-padding"});
var textField = $("<input>", {type: "text", name: "reservation_type", class: "form-control m-b-1", value: extra_crew });
newDiv.append(textField);
$('#extra_crew_area').append(newDiv);
```

You could condense it slightly:

```
$('#extra_crew_area').append(
    $("<div>", {id: "foo", class: "col-sm-12 m-t-10 m-b-10 no-padding"}).append(
        $("<input>", {type: "text", name: "reservation_type", class: "form-control m-b-1", value: extra_crew })
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove '+extra_crew+' from text field and add below js

```
$('#extra_crew_area').find(".form-control:last input[type='text']").val(extra_crew);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have test your code , it will work . but is it your server code here

`<%= text_field_tag :reservation_type, "", class: "form-control m-b-10", :value => "'+extra_crew+'" %>`

I think it's ruby, and it will not run on browser

Comment: It does not matter whether it is ruby, the problem is i get extra_crew as string instead of value probably cuz of the quotation marks